# Using xpath to return a specific item value based on attribute value without a loop

Tags: php, xml

We're integrating with opensrs and they still work with xml which is terrible :(

Here is a returned XML response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE OPS_envelope SYSTEM "ops.dtd">
      <OPS_envelope>
           <header>
        <version>0.9</version>
        </header>
       <body>
        <data_block>
         <dt_assoc>
          <item key="action">REPLY</item>
          <item key="attributes">
           <dt_assoc>
            <item key="status">available</item>
           </dt_assoc>
          </item>
          <item key="is_success">1</item>
          <item key="response_text">Domain available</item>
          <item key="response_code">210</item>
          <item key="protocol">XCP</item>
          <item key="object">DOMAIN</item>
         </dt_assoc>
        </data_block>
       </body>
</OPS_envelope>
```

I am trying to obtain the value of the the element:

`<item key="response_code">210</item>`

so trying to get a value of 210 in this example.

Using xpath, I can get the path query, run a loop and get the value this way:

```
$xml = $r->xml;
$code = $xml->xpath('//item');
foreach($code AS $i) {
      if($i->attributes()->key == "response_code") {
            $code = $i;
      }
}
if(isset($code)) {
    // We got a code!
    echo  $code;
}
exit;
```

This however seems highly inefficient and I simply cannot make peace with this being the best way to obtain it. I have seen some hacks where you convert the xml using json_decode(json_encode($xml)) which almost returns a workable json string but as there are a number of elements called item I am forced to work with an numeric array which may not always present the correct value as the correct array element.

Am i stuck between a rock and a hard place or is there a better way to obtain the value?

EDIT

So it seems I can try something like this:

```
$xml->xpath("//item[@key='response_code']")[0];
```

The above however assumes that there will be a item with the appropriate attribue called "response_code" - I could do a "is_array" first on the value before assuming the value is set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nothing is found you get an empty array back. You have to do something like that:

```
$nlist = $xml->xpath("//item[@key='response_code']");

if(!empty($nlist)){
  echo (string)$nlist[0];
}
else {
  echo 'not found';
}
```

The xpath expression now only searches for "item" elements with the special attribute. This expression searches for all elements:

```
$nlist = $xml->xpath("//*[@key='response_code']");
```

Answer (score 0):

DOMXpath::evaluate() can return scalar values directly - and this needs a typecast in the Xpath expression:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMxpath($document);

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(//item[@key="response_code"])')  
);
```

Output:

```
string(3) "210"
```